# GitLab 8.15.0 restore backup not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

I am trying to restore a backup from gitlab A into gitlab B. They are on the same version (8.15.0) but when I try to restore using this commands:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq
sudo gitlab-ctl stop unicorn
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1482434794_2016_12_22
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:122:in `exist?'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:122:in `unpack'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:restore
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The server have a clean install just with the root user created. Git lab is running and I already have run once:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed Omnibus version. The command I use to make the backup is

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

And the generated file is like this:

```
1482434794_2016_12_22_gitlab_backup.tar
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put only one backup in `/var/opt/gitlab/backups/` you can use command `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab: backup: restore` without `BACKUP = 1482434794_2016_12_22`.

This helped in my case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fix it for me to.

Comment: This isn't really a fix, considering that this just forces a default.  Has anyone found a way to specify a backup and made it work with a specific stamp?

Comment: I had the exact same issue, also on Ubuntu 16.04, importing a backup from Ubuntu 14.04. Skipping the BACKUP parameter made it work.

Comment: @abegosum Yes, this is a workaround. Actual state of fix can be tracked in [Gitlab issue #26090](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26090)

Answer (score 2):

This might help others reading this post, I was able to restore my backup by specifying the full backup file name (not just the timestamp)

I am using *gitlab-ce 8.15.4-ce.1* (omnibus installation) with *Ubuntu 16.04*

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1484655963_2017_01_17_gitlab_backup.tar
```